# Proper usage of .includes and .joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have 3 models

Options:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :key, :name
  belongs_to :item_options
end
```

ItemOptions

```
class ItemOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :option
end
```

and Item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_options
  has_many :options, :through => :item_options
end
```

And I need my controller to return all items with their options in JSON format so i'm trying to use .includes but with no luck:

```
items = Item
  .order('id')
  .where(manufacturer)
  .where('is_active')
render :json => {:data => items.offset(offset), :total => items.count}.to_json(
  :include => :options
)
```

Result does not contain options but i see in console there are appropriate DB requests. However it does only works if i use :include inside to_json:

```
items = Item
  .order('id')
  .where(manufacturer)
  .where('is_active')
render :json => {:data => items.offset(offset), :total => items.count}.to_json(
  :include => :options
)
```

So the first question is what am i doing wrong so that .include does not work?

But i aslo have problem with working code. I need options to be joined with item_options because options just store options name, options group id and so on, when item_options keeps value for defined option for defined item. And so i'm trying to extend my code as follows:

```
items = Item
  .order('id')
  .where(manufacturer)
  .where('is_active')
render :json => {:data => items.offset(offset), :total => items.count}.to_json(
  :include => {
    :options => {
      :joins => :item_options
    }
  }
)
```

But still, i receive options not beeing joined with item_options. Why?

Also if i use joins inside optoins do i need to define has_many through in items if they loaded without additional information in item_options?

**========== UPDATE:**

For now i just replaced an `options` relation to method in Items model:

```
item = Item
  .includes(:item_options)
  .find(params[:id])
render :json => item.to_json(:methods => :options)
```

and in Item model:

```
has_many :item_options
def options
  self.item_options.select('item_options.value, options.name, options.is_feature, options.root').joins('left join options on options.id = item_options.option_id')
end
```

Don't know, however, if this solution is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Your calling `to_json` on a hash and not on the model, and Hash knows nothing about includes or joins.

Try putting your json options on the model

```
data = items.offset(offset).as_json(include: :options)
render json: {data: data, total: items.count}
```

Also, I think your `Option belongs_to :item_options` should be `Option has_many :item_options`

Using :include within as_json is an instruction to the ActiveModel json serializer telling it to include data from associations in the output JSON.

[ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)
([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb))

The joins and includes methods are part of ActiveRecord and are used to add join conditions and perform eager loading.

[ActiveRecord joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)
[ActiveRecord includes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: but why it dos not work with just Item.includes(:options)? Why i need to put it in to_json?

Comment: Calling includes(:options) populates all of the options in memory so that when you call items.options.first no query is executed. But this does not instruct the JSON serializer that it needs to include them, that is where the hash of instructions comes in. They're not related to each other except in name.

Comment: i tried to extend your code so that options was joined with item_options - "data = items.offset(offset).as_json(:include => {:options => {:joins => :item_options}})" but it does not have effect, can you say why?

Comment: Because the options your passing to as_json are instructions for the json serializer, not instructions for the database query, and the json serializer knows nothing about joins. I'll edit my answer with some links.

Comment: So I should do something like .includes(:item_options => {:joins=>:options}) to include optoins joined with item_options? It is wrong and I'm confised about how to achieve what I want (

Comment: `as_json(:include => {:item_options => {:include => :options}})` includes and joins are not related to JSON output, `include` is, see the docs for ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON that i linked.